# How to import custom jar (not gwt module) to gwt project

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I struggle with adding my custom jar to gwt compiler.

I've check tons of internet and can not find answer.
I found solution to add module.gwt.xml file to this custom jar library and import it in my  gwt app app.gwt.xml as follow: `<inherits name="com.ia.ia"/>`
But this will make my custom java library gwt aware and this is anti pattern for me. As I will spoil backend common library with gwt (which is just UI detail).

I would like to follow approach with `<source path='maintenance'/>` entry but I can configure it only for local java classes. I do not know how to do this for external jar.

Please help

**Here are steps I've done already:**

I've added source plugin to pom.xml of my custom jar as follow:

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

so the custom jar builds generate 2 jars, normal and with sources.

I've added dependency to my gwt project
ui/pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ia</groupId>
        <artifactId>ia-maintenance-api</artifactId>
        <version>${qiasphere-maintenance.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ia</groupId>
        <artifactId>ia-maintenance-api</artifactId>
        <version>${ia-maintenance.version}</version>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

When I do compile gwt I am getting error:

> [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 16: No source code is available for type com.ia.maintenance.api.network.wifi.WifiSecurityType; did you forget to inherit a required module?

this is my gwt UI app module file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.9.0//EN"
        "http://gwtproject.org/doctype/2.9.0/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to="app">
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.editor.Editor"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>
    <inherits name='com.github.nalukit.nalu.Nalu'/>
    <inherits name='com.github.nalukit.nalu.plugin.elemental2.NaluPluginElemental2'/>
    <inherits name='org.dominokit.domino.ui.DominoUI'/>
    <inherits name="org.dominokit.rest.Rest"/>
    <inherits name="org.jresearch.threetenbp.gwt.time.module"/>

    <entry-point class='com.ia.ia.app.ui.APP'/>

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code (java and java script) -->
    <source path='ui'/>
    <source path='shared'/>

</module>
```

custom jar library doesnt have any module.gwt.xml file as I do not wanna spoil simple backend jar with frontend details.

So I need to configure it in gwt ui app.

Maybe some maven plugin that will get source *.java file from this custom jar library and put it in target directory like: `target/classes/com.ia.ia.maintenance` so gwt compiler could pick it up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need to modify the jar, all you need is to create a gwt.xml file in your own project/client module that has its sources tag points to the pojos package.

What I would do is to create a package in my client module `com.ia.ia.maintenance` and add a new gwt.xml there `Maintenance.gwt.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>
  <source path="" />
</module>
```

now in your own application gwt.xml you inherit this new module.