# No source code is available for type org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority

Tags: java, maven, spring-security, gwt, gwt-rpc

- I have a legacy multi-module GWT project.
- One of the modules contains the DTO and Enum classes.
- One of the DTO classes extends the `org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority` class, so in the pom.xml it has the maven *spring-security-core* dependency of *org.springframework.security*.
- When I tried to run the `package` command, i got the message:

> ***No source code is available for type***
> ***org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority; did you forget to***
> ***inherit a required module?***

- I tried to apply solutions that were recommended in some posts that I found with similar messages, I even found [one that related the same error](https://groups.google.com/g/google-web-toolkit/c/-pTzWanmFv0), but none of those solutions worked for me.

**Could you please help me figure out what is causing this error and how I could fix it?**

---

To reproduce the issue you can follow the steps I did:

1. I used [GWT Archetypes](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes/) to create a basic project called `GWTRPCModular`; and:

   - JDK 17 (but also I tried it with 8)
   - Eclipse 2023-03
   - Apache Maven 3.8.6
   - GWT 2.10.0
2. The project was generated with 3 modules: `GWTRPCModular-client`, `GWTRPCModular-server` and `GWTRPCModular-shared`.
3. I added a module called `GWTRPCModular-model` for the DTOs *(similar to my legacy project)* and in the pom.xml I added the necessary dependencies.
4. I included the `<source path="model" />` to the *.gwt.xml file.
5. I created the `UserSessionDTO` class

```
import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

public class UserSessionDTO extends User {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6391317902265663080L;

    public UserSessionDTO(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

6. I ran the `mvn clean install`
7. Finally I ran the `mvn package` and the message appeared:

```
...
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:1.0.1:compile (default-compile) GWTRPCModular-client ---
[INFO] Compiling module com.foo.gwtmodular.App
[INFO]    Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.foo.gwtmodular.model.dto.UserSessionDTO'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'com/foo/gwtmodular/model/dto/UserSessionDTO.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 8: No source code is available for type org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 12: No source code is available for type org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority; did you forget to inherit a required module?
...
```

If you need anything else to review this case, please let me know.

**I thank you in advance for any help you can provide!**

Comment: If this spring library is being used in the client, the maven artifact for the spring library must include the source files (.java) so that GWT can compile the source.  Or if the source is in a separate artifact then that must be added as a dependency too.

Comment: Thanks, @RobertNewton, I really appreciate your response.

I added the "sources" as a dependency in the pom.xml of both client and model modules, but the error message still appears. Is there anything else I should add/modify?

`
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
 <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
 <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
`

Answer (score 0):

In your GWT (*.gwt.xml) module file, you need an `<inherits>` tag for this spring dependency also.

This spring library probably does not come with its own GWT module file though, so you will need to create your own.  In your client project you could create a package such as `org.springframework.security`, create a GWT module file for the spring library and put it in the package.  Then you can inherit it in your main GWT module file

Refer to this question/answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70538165/1920835

Comment: I did what you recommended: I created the package _com.focussscm.gwtmodular.model_ in my client project and I created the Model.gwt.xml file; but, many more messages of the same type appeared for libraries that are somehow related to org.sprintframework.security.

Compiling module com.focussscm.gwtmodular.App
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'org.s...ion.SessionInformation'
     [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/.../s..re//spring-security-core-sources.jar!/..SessionInformation.java'
      [ERROR] Line 52: No source code is available for type org.springframework.util.Assert; did

Comment: what paths did you put in your <module> <source> tags in the module file?

Comment: I just realized that I gave you the wrong path names _(sorry about that)_; actually the package was called _org.springframework.security_, the module file was called Security.gwt.xml and I used <source path="" /> in it.

Comment: So now I assume you are not getting "no source code" errors for classes in the org.springframework.security package (and it's subpackages)?
But you are getting those errors for classes in different packages?  If so, you will need to go though a similar procedure as before.
Also note that GWT doesn't emulate all classes in the JRE, so if spring is using certain classes that aren't emulated you could be in trouble:  https://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html#runtime

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the "no source code" error for classes in org.springframework.security package, after following the steps you (and your refered question/answer) recommended.

Comment: And you are inheriting this Security gwt module in your main gwt module?  You could try the community on Gitter, they should have experience with what you are trying to do: https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt

Comment: Yes, I add the <inherits name="org.springframework.security.Security" /> to gwt module. I will try on Gitter as well, thanks!